# Bootstrap 5 tabs arent changing on screen sizes 577px and below

Tags: responsive-design, tabs, bootstrap-5

I am able to toggle across the tabs on larger devices but on the smaller devices, it does not work. There are also no errors in the console. The tab is also wrapped in a div that has a z-index of -1. I need it to have a z-index of -1 so that when I scroll up it goes under another div. If I remove the z-index from the wrapper I am able to click the tabs.

I cannot add a higher z-index to the div I'd like these tab items to scroll under because a dropdown list from the navbar will be hidden behind it.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs innerTab" id="profileTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#personal" type="button"
            role="tab" aria-controls="personal" aria-selected="true">Personal Information</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="account-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#account" type="button"
            role="tab" aria-controls="account" aria-selected="false">Account
            Information</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="kyc-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#kyc" type="button" role="tab"
            aria-controls="kyc" aria-selected="false">
            Documents</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="password-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#password" type="button"
            role="tab" aria-controls="password" aria-selected="false">Password change</button>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="profileTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane show active" id="personal" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="personal-tab">
        P
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="account" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="account-tab">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="kyc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="kyc-tab">K
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="password" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="password-tab">P
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u tried wrap or change containers into "label", may be need add them display: block; and remove some padding/margin to keep your layout

Comment: I updated my question with something I just discovered. @Damian Chudobiński